# How to avoid migration conflict between local and remote server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If there was a migration missed on local machine,

After a long time, I found the problem that local server DB scheme has changed but Server hasn't.

There is no migration file on local machine, I don't know why.

So I did a migration on the server,

but the new added migration file will conflict with the local machine.

What's the better practice to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Dump server database and create from the dump a development database.

Answer (score 0):

you can trap the statement in either a `column_exists?` or `table_exists?` function